# List of Files in a Notepad from one Folder/Subfolder from one UNC path to Another UNC path

Tags: copy, unc

I am trying this below Batch Script to copy files from one UNC Path (STG Server) to another UNC (PROD server).
However it's showing error that UNC paths are not supported. Could someone help me out on this?

```
@echo off
set src_folder= "UNC path 1"   
set dst_folder= "UNC path 2"
set File_List = "UNC path 1\Folder A\File-list.txt"
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (%File_List%) DO 
(
xcopy /S/E "%src_folder%\%%i" "%dst_folder%"
)
pause
```

Comment: When UNC is not supported, you can do a drive mapping.

Comment: @Dominique, 
Hi. Can you show me how to use this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This below script has worked, even with UNC Paths -

```
@echo off
set src_folder= SOURCE Path
set dst_folder= DESTINATION PATH
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (FileList.txt) DO (
    xcopy /S/E "%src_folder%\%%i" "%dst_folder%"
)
cmd /k
```